# Is it possible to Takeown.exe of a folder for the "Everyone" user, on Windows

Tags: command-line-interface, permissions

I can use takeown.exe to give the currently logged in user ownership of a folder. But when I try:

```
takeown /s jimswork8 /u Everyone /f c:\test /R /D Y
```

It just gives ownership to the currently logged in user. I CAN do it if I use the UI, so I would think it is possible, but I just can't get the syntax right.

Thanks

Comment: Everyone isn't a user, it's a group.

Comment: Good point. Can a group be added this way?

Comment: I don't think so, as if it is allowed, they don't provide the syntax for it. However, you can do the "Administrators" group by using /a switch. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

takeown is a leftover from the days when Microsoft insisted you couldn't set the ownership of a file to someone other than the person logged on. I don't know why the tool lets you specify a username, but it will not honor it as far as I know.

`icacls` will allow you to set the owner from the command line. But it will not update ACEs. If the file/folder is simply inheriting permissions, following the `/setowner` command with a `/reset` command will fix the ACEs.

Comment: Somehow it fails to set new owner even though I can do it through Explorer.

Comment: For its own sadistic pleasure, Microsoft showed a preference for `takeown` in the help screen of the `/setowner` option in `icacls`.

Comment: My `icacls DIR /setowner DOMAIN\DOMUSER /t /c /q` showed Access denied, but pushing the ownership to the local admin group `takeown /f DIR /a /r /d y`, then giving a full permission to that group `BUILTIN\Administrators` (I belong in it and I logged in as a local user in that group) with `icacls DIR /reset /t /c /q`, `icacls DIR /grant BUILTIN\Administrators:F /t /c /q` opened the door to changing the ownership, `icacls DIR /setowner DOMAIN\DOMUSER /t /c /q`. Caveat: takeown does not grok the \\?\DIR notation making it impossible to process long paths.

Answer (score 4):

This set owner of folder or file to group `Everyone` - works on windows 7 and above:

```
icacls "full path of file with file extension" /setowner "Everyone" /T /C
```